# App Scripts - Copy (values only) a row of data from one google spreadsheet to another (based on checked box) and deleting it from the original one

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Data Source Spreadsheet = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1weqJpRcou0QWpekYg-eqBXUupqSoVC5w4Tc04sFTgWs/edit?usp=sharing"

Data Destination Spreadsheet == "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10Wa76S-slzmtCCePDChMJrLJYaAzA6H_NlpnJKWIfNU/edit?usp=sharing"

```
function onEdit(e){
if(e.range.columnStart != 28 || e.value != "TRUE") return;
var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var source = sh.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
var dest = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10Wa76S-slzmtCCePDChMJrLJYaAzA6H_NlpnJKWIfNU/edit').getSheetByName("Completed");
dest.activate().getRange(dest.getLastRow()+1,1,1,25).setValues(source.getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,25).getValues());
source.deleteRow(e.range.rowStart);
}
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask], [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks), [mcve] and [Tag Info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guessing that this is probably what you want:

```
function onMyEdit(e){
  const sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName()=='Sheet1' && e.range.columnStart == 28 && e.value == "TRUE") {
    const dsh=SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10Wa76S-slzmtCCePDChMJrLJYaAzA6H_NlpnJKWIfNU/edit').getSheetByName("Completed");
    dsh.getRange(dsh.getLastRow()+1,1,1,25).setValues(sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,25).getValues());
    sh.deleteRow(e.range.rowStart);
  }
}
```

It needs to be an installable onedit trigger because it requires permission to move and delete data.

#### Reference:

- [Simple Triggers: Restrictions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#restrictions)
- [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)
- [Event Objects: Edit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit)